# elementary abelian subgroups with centralizers not connected

Tags: algebraic-groups, abelian-groups, weyl-group, classical-groups, centralisers

Let $G =$ PGL$_{8}(\textbf{C})$. Let $a, b, c, d$ be four representatives of conjugacy classes of involutions in $G$ where $$a = \begin{pmatrix}
-1 & 0\\
0 & I_{7}
\end{pmatrix}, b = \begin{pmatrix}
-I_{2} & 0\\
0 & I_{6}
\end{pmatrix},$$ $$c = \begin{pmatrix}
-I_{3} & 0\\
0 & I_{5}
\end{pmatrix}, d = \begin{pmatrix}
-I_{4} & 0\\
0 & I_{4}
\end{pmatrix}.$$
We are interested in the elementary abelian 2-subgroups $E$ with $C_{G}(E)$ not connected. Denote $C_{G}(E)$ and $N_{G}(E)$ by $C$ and $N$, respectively. $T_{m}$ is a $m$-dimensional torus. Calculation gives the conjugacy class distribution, centraliser and normaliser info of all such subgroups:

| cls dist | $C$ | $C/C^{\circ}$ | $N/C$ |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| [0,0,0,1] | $A_{3}A_{3}T_{1}$ | 2 | 1 |
| [0,1,0,2] | $A_{2}A_{2}T_{3}$ | 2 | 2 |
| [0,2,0,5] | $A_{1}A_{1}T_{5}$ | 2 | $D_{4}$ |
| [0,4,0,11] | $T_{7}$ | 2 | $H$ of order 192 |
| [0,0,0,3] | $A_{1}A_{1}A_{1}A_{1}T_{3}$ | 2^2 | $GL(2,2)$ |
| [0,0,0,7] | $T_{7}$ | 2^3 | $GL(3,2)$ |

Some observations made:

1. For every group $E$ with $C/C^{\circ} \cong 2$, $N/C$ is isomorphic to a subgroup of $H$.
2. For the 5th group, its $N/C$ is the automorphism group of $C/C^{\circ}$. The same holds for the 6th group.

Question: Can we generalize these observations? I checked PGL$_{n}$ for $n=4,6,10,12$ and found them true. Are there any references regarding this? Thank you.